# White background surrounding the flash <embed> tag in Google Chrome

Tags: css, flash, google-chrome, background, embed

A picture is worth a thousand words and so I'll start off with it

[image: White background around embed tag]

As you can see, there is white background appearing in Chrome while in Firefox, the movie fits perfectly.

Here is the embed code:

```
<embed id="movie" src="movie.swf" loop="false" menu="false" quality="best" 
bgcolor="#ffffff" width="250" height="250" scale="aspect" name="movie" 
align="middle" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="false" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
flashvars="shutter_enabled=1&amp;shutter_url=shutter.mp3&amp;width=250&amp;
height=250&amp;server_width=250&amp;server_height=250">
```

For the time being, I've used `bgcolor=#e0efe8` to merge it with background. But what I'm curious about is why doesn't the movie fit perfectly as it does in Firefox?

I tried to look at css but right clicking over it brings up the flash settings menu.
The embed tag is withing a `td` and the `table` has `cellspacing = "4"` and `cellpadding = "3"`, but I don't think that would cause a problem. The table, tr, or td doesn't have a height property defined so I guess we can tick that off of 'to check' list too.

Is there anything else from my side that needs to be provided to come up a solution?

**UPDATE**

Throwing in the HTML too if that helps:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <embed id="movie" src="movie.swf" loop="false" menu="false" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" scale="aspect" name="movie" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="shutter_enabled=1&amp;shutter_url=shutter.mp3&amp;width=250&amp;height=250&amp;server_width=250&amp;server_height=250" align="middle" height="250" width="250">
             </td>   
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Finally managed to view the CSS through Firebug lite. Here is the SS:

[image: CSS]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mis spelled cellpadding.  Hopefully that is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Opps! That's a typo on my part. It's fine in the actual code.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that recreates the problem?

Comment: @BillyMoat Wouldn't I require a .swf file to test it in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll need to have a look at your CSS file or inline style code, have you tried setting the td padding property to zero?

CSS code:

```
td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Edit1: If that doesn't work, maybe this css property:

```
border-collapse: collapse
```

Edit2: Try using these CSS properties:

```
position: relative;
overflow: auto;
```

Source (someone else having a similar problem): http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/2EqmQiwApz4

Comment: Yep already tried that. There is no inline sytling. Let me try to use firebug to get a list of css being applied to it. I found a way past the flash settings menu

Comment: Maybe try using width="100%" in your embed tag, or maybe try taking out the parameters: "width=250&amp;height=250&amp;server_width=250&amp;server_height=250" from the flashvars property.